# Displaying non-featured recent products products with a shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, wordpress-featured-image

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to get "recent products" that are no featured with this shortcode:

```
[product_attribute attribute='_featured' filter='no' orderby="date" order="desc"]
```

**But it doesn't seem to take any effect.**

How can I achieve this?

*Please do not propose 3rd party plugins*.*

Thanks

***More info in official [Shortcodes included with WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this shortcode, **attributes** works with **variable products** and your actual shortcode can't really work **as featured product functionality is not an attribute**.

You should better try to use **[`[recent_products]`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6)** shortcodes instead, setting in all your featured products a "Featured" category *(with "featured" slug)*…

Then you could use the shortcode this way:

```html
[recent_products category='featured' operator='NOT IN']
```

You don't need to set **`orderby`** and **`order`** arguments as the defaults ones are:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'per_page' => '12',
    'columns'  => '4',
    'orderby'  => 'date',
    'order'    => 'desc',
    'category' => '',  // Slugs
    'operator' => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
), $atts, 'recent_products' );
```

See related documentation: [WC_Class Shortcodes - Recent Products shortcode source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shortcodes.html#281-310)